# NG Test cannot use Karma custom launchers

Tags: angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to run Karma via the Angular CLI headlessly for CI, but I can't get Karma to use my custom launcher.

As per [this page on the Angular website](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome) I am using a `customLauncher` property in my Karma config. But when I try to run my tests with `ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI`, I get an error that my custom launcher is not registered.

```
    01 01 2021 14:10:10.121:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.2.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
    01 01 2021 14:10:10.126:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessCI with concurrency unlimited
    01 01 2021 14:10:10.127:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "ChromeHeadlessCI": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
    01 01 2021 14:10:10.128:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error
     at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\trimb\Dropbox\7_Workspaces\weather\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:213:27)
     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
     at Server.emit (events.js:327:22)
     at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
     at emitListeningNT (net.js:1352:10)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Here is my Karma config:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
      plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
      ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/weather'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: true
    });
  };
```

Here is the command I am running from my package.json via npm:

```
"test::cci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI",
```

I am not sure where to go from here. It is a bug with Karma? A misconfiguration on my part (the more likely culprit)? I don't know. All this "code" is pretty much boilerplate stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. It was, of course, a configuration issue. There is a property in the `angular.json` file to specify a custom `karmaConfig` path.

I am not sure how it happened, but it had an incorrect path of `src/karma.config.js` Karma still ran when I ran `ng test` because ([as per Angualr.io](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configuration))

> The karma.conf.js file is a partial Karma configuration file. The CLI constructs the full runtime configuration in memory, based on application structure specified in the angular.json file, supplemented by karma.conf.js.

The error I was getting about my `customLoader being missing` is technically correct since Karma was not loading my config. So if the Karma config file specified in the angular.json file is not found, the CLI continues and makes a "default" config for Karma to run.

*My two cents*: there should be some error outputted to the console that the specified karma config could not be found, but alas, there is not. Check your paths people!